# Django 1.8, makemigrations not detecting newly added app

Tags: python, django

I have an existing django project with a,b,c apps. All of them are included in installed apps in settings file. They have their own models with for which the migrations have already been ran. Now, if I add a new app d, add a model to it, include it in installed apps and try to run a blanket makemigrations using `python manage.py makemigrations` I get a `no changes detected` message. Shouldn't the behaviour be like it detects a new app and run an initial migration for that? I know I can do it manually using `python manage.py makemigrations d` but I want to do it with using `python manage.py makemigrations` command. Can someone provide explanation for this behavior?

Comment: Are you entirely sure you added `d` to `installed_apps`?

Comment: @mccc yes. I was able to reproduce the same scenario on my colleague's machine as well

Comment: Did you create the app using the `startapp` command? Or did you just create the `d` folder?

Comment: I used startapp command. There appeared a folder called migrations with __init__.py in it. After which I added a model in models.py then ran python manage.py makemigrations

Comment: What version of django and python are you using? I just tried a new virtualenv, with django 1.8.5, started a new project and a new app, added a single model with a single field, and added the new app into the list of installed_apps and it worked fine

Comment: @hack.augusto django version 1.8.1 and python 3.4. Can you now add a new app manually using startapp, include it in installed apps and run command 'python manage.py makemigrations' ?

Comment: @RajeshYogeshwar worked fine. After the answer of @Hedde I created a third app and checked for the folder `migrations` and the `__init__.py` and they were generated. Also I tried with python2.7.10

Comment: Add a simple model with one field to the third app, save it and run python manage.py makemigrations. Does it run? Do not specify app name after makemigrations

Answer (score 30):

If you create a new app manually and add it to the INSTALLED_APPS setting without adding a migrations module inside it, the system will not pick up changes as this is not considered a migrations configured app.

The startapp command automatically adds the migrations module inside of your new app.

**startapp structure**

```
foo/
    __init__.py
    admin.py
    models.py
    migrations/
        __init__.py
    tests.py
    views.py
```

Comment: I understand that and agree to it. My question is, after I add an app manually using startapp (with migrations module inside of it automatically added by startapp) and include a simple model inside the models.py in the same app why doesn't a python manage.py makemigrations command executed right after it pick up the changes that a new app has been added with a model and create a respective table?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your scenario. In my case when adding a new application, either manually or via the startapp command, under these conditions changes are picked up as expected.

Comment: Anyways thanks. Logically it shouldn't happen, I don't know what might be causing it.

Comment: python manage.py makemigrations foo will generate the migrations directory for that app

Answer (score 1):

There are a few steps necessary for Django to pick up the newly created app and the models created inside it.

Let's assume you created a new app called `messaging` with the command `python manage.py startapp messaging` or by manually adding the following directory structure:

```
 - project_name
     - messaging
       - migrations
         - __init__.py
       - __init__.py
       - admin.py
       - apps.py
       - models.py
       - tests.py
       - views.py
     - project_name
       - __init__.py
       - settings.py
       - urls.py
       - wsgi.py
     - manage.py
```

In `settings.py` you need to add the app to `INSTALLED_APPS` like this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'messaging.apps.MessagingConfig'
]
```

After adding models to `models.py`, e.g:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import DO_NOTHING


class Thread(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=2000)    

class Message(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=2000, blank=True, null=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=False, null=False, on_delete=DO_NOTHING)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Thread, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=DO_NOTHING)
```

Django will automatically make migrations when running the command

`python manage.py makemigrations`

or if you only want to create migrations for the `messaging` app, you can do

`python manage.py makemigrations messaging`.

The output should be:

```
Migrations for 'messaging':   
messaging\migrations\0001_initial.py
  - Create model Thread
  - Create model Message
```

If Django still does not pick up your new app and models, please make sure that your python classes correctly inherits from `models.Model` as in `Thread(models.Model):`, and that you define some Django model fields inside the class, e.g. `text = models.CharField(max_length=2000, blank=True, null=False)`

After your migrations successfully have been created, you can applythem using

`python manage.py migrate` (applies all migrations)

or

`python manage.py migrate messaging` (applies messaging migrations only)